# How to use javascript to create a string of numbers based on current time?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I used to use the code to create a string of numbers for my filenames to avoid duplicates. What it does is that it will send me a string of numbers of the exact current time that is very accurate (like 1/1000000000 of a second). I don't remember how I did it anymore since I kept just copy and paste my old codes. Do anyone know how to do that?

Comment: [`new Date().getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) returns `Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good reference at MDN about the Javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) constructor/object. But basically, in older environments, do.

`new Date().getTime()`

In newer environments you can do

`Date.now()`

Both return an `Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).`

You can also do

`new Date().valueOf()`

but it could be less reliable than those above.

Answer (score 2):

The current time in javascript is only provided to a number of milliseconds.  If generating multiple filenames at once, you may get the same current time when requested multiple times during the same operation.  So, if you want a totally unique number (with even more uniqueness than the current milliseconds so you can generate a number of these in a tight loop), you can combine the time with a randomly generated value like this:

```
function makeUnique(base) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    return base + now + random;
}

makeUnique("test");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dpZLC/

If you want the filename to always be the same number of digits, you can zero pad the random number like this:

```
function makeUnique(base) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    // zero pad random
    random = "" + random;
    while (random.length < 5) {
        random = "0" + random;
    }
    return base + now + random;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create retrieve the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the epoch by using the getTime method of the Date object.

var now = new Date();
console.log(now.getTime());

Comment: A [`Unix timestamp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is different.`the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970`. You would have to divide the javascript timestamp by 1000 to get seconds.

Comment: You're right, it's the wrong term, I'm updating the answer.